# redistribute someone

Tags: meaning

In the movie *Love Actually*, the prime minister asks his secretary to redistribute an employee, I think, because he was falling in love with that particular employee, Natalie.

> Redistribute Natalie.

I can guess from the context that he wants her away to stop himself from thinking of her all the time, but I can't be sure because I couldn't find an authentic reference in dictionaries. However, I found a similar question online though the answers were contradictory and the context was not exactly what I described.

Does he mean *give her a difficult task to do (to get her busier)*, *reassign her*, *relocate her somewhere (so he can't see her at all)* or maybe *fire her*?

Comment: I'm not sure how contradictory those answers you found would be. To me, its core meaning would be "move her to somewhere else", but move how? I'm not sure. It sounds a bit like political jargon, IMO.

Comment: @Damkerng T one of the answers was _give a difficult task based on her skill_ which I think wasn't relevant at all in this context and the second was simply picking on the sentence and rejecting it as a wrong use of _redistribute_. Neither actually answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found very few examples online where **redistribute** was followed by a person.

> The plans include a complex formula to **redistribute** asylum-seekers
>   around the EU from countries facing a huge influx, as Greece did last
>   year. Economist May 5, 2016

I can understand that in this example it means relocate.

In thefreedictionary.com **reassign** was given as a synonym to redistribute.
*Give her a difficult task to do or fire her* sound the least possible meanings.

Comment: +1 and another question, do you recommend using this word any way?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would never use "redistribute" to mean reassign a person to another area, but that's what he meant. As you realized, he was falling in love and didn't want to embarrass himself by having to see her on a regular basis. He definitely did not want her fired.